# Why am I unable to apply height and width to my SVG path elements?

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox

Here is my HTML:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .side-svg {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px red solid;
    }
    
    .sto {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .rect-svg {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .rectangle {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body class="body">
              
        <svg class="side-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve"> 
          <path class="st0" d="M25,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,16.7,23.3,18,25,18z M24,14h2v2h-2V14z M25,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,24.7,23.3,26,25,26z M24,22h2v2h-2V22z M17,26c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3
          c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,24.7,15.3,26,17,26z M16,22h2v2h-2V22z M28,0H6C3.8,0,2,1.8,2,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h22
          c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H6c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V8h26V28z M30,6H4V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h22
          c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V6z M17,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,16.7,15.3,18,17,18z M16,14h2v2h-2V14z M9,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,24.7,7.3,26,9,26z M8,22h2v2H8V22z M9,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3
          c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,16.7,7.3,18,9,18z M8,14h2v2H8V14z"/>
        </svg>
                
            
        <svg class="side-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="st0" d="M18,16.4c1.3-1.7,2-3.9,2-6.4c0-5.5-4-10-9-10C6,0,2,4.5,2,10c0,2.4,0.8,4.6,2,6.4c-2.3,0.8-4,3-4,5.6v4
          c0,3.3,2.7,6,6,6h10c3.3,0,6-2.7,6-6v-4C22,19.4,20.3,17.2,18,16.4z M4,10c0-4.4,3.1-8,7-8c3.9,0,7,3.6,7,8s-3.1,8-7,8
          C7.1,18,4,14.4,4,10z M20,25.5c0,2.5-2.2,4.5-4.9,4.5H6.9C4.2,30,2,28,2,25.5v-3c0-2.1,1.6-3.9,3.8-4.4C7.2,19.3,9,20,11,20
          c2,0,3.8-0.7,5.2-1.9c2.2,0.5,3.8,2.2,3.8,4.4V25.5z M23,8h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1
          C22,7.6,22.4,8,23,8z M31,24h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,24.4,31.6,24,31,24z M31,12h-8
          c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,12.4,31.6,12,31,12z M31,18h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6
          c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,18.4,31.6,18,31,18z"/>
        </svg>
                  
                  
        <svg class="side-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="st0" d="M14,0h-2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v28c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C16,0.9,15.1,0,14,0z M14,29
          c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V3c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M4,9H2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2
          c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V11C6,9.9,5.1,9,4,9z M4,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V12c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M24,16h-2
          c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v12c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V18C26,16.9,25.1,16,24,16z M24,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V19
          c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z"/>
        </svg>
                
                  
        <svg class="side-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="st0" d="M26,24H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1
          c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,24.4,26.6,24,26,24z M11,27.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4
          c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,26.3,12.3,27.4,11,27.4z M26,8H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3C9.1,5,7.6,6.3,7.1,8H6
          C5.4,8,5,8.4,5,9c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,8.4,26.6,8,26,8z M11,11.4
          c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,10.3,12.3,11.4,11,11.4z M26,16h-2.1
          c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h10.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26
          c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,16.4,26.6,16,26,16z M20,19.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4
          C22.4,18.3,21.3,19.4,20,19.4z M28,0H4C1.8,0,0,1.8,0,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h24c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28
          c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H4c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h24c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V28z"/>
        </svg>
    
    
        <svg class="rect-svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
          <rect class="rectangle"></rect>
        </svg>
                  
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I was experiemnting with SVG's and was wondering why my SVG with a rectangle element responded to height and width properites applied to it, but not the path elements in the four inline SVG's above.

I wanted to expand the SVG to be 100% of the viewport, thus setting 100% for both height and width, but this didn't work like it did for the rectange SVG. Why is this?

I set the same viewport attribute for all the inline SVG's as well, so why isn't this working?

Comment: Try using `viewBox="0 0 32 32"` instead of `viewBox="0 0 200 200"` An SVG element with a viewBox and no width and/or height will take all the width available

Comment: I've used `viewBox="0 0 32 32"` because in your code you have enable-background:new 0 0 32 32 usually set to the same value as viewBox. However if you need a different value you can use the bounding box of the path inside. To get the bounding box you may use the method `getBBox()`

Answer (score 3):

As I've commented you need to use `viewBox="0 0 32 32"` instead of `viewBox="0 0 200 200"`. However I understand you want *to have the `viewbox` to fit exactly the viewport* in this case

```css
svg{width:100px;border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg class="side-svg" viewBox="2 0 30 32" > 
          <path class="st0" d="M25,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,16.7,23.3,18,25,18z M24,14h2v2h-2V14z M25,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,24.7,23.3,26,25,26z M24,22h2v2h-2V22z M17,26c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3
          c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,24.7,15.3,26,17,26z M16,22h2v2h-2V22z M28,0H6C3.8,0,2,1.8,2,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h22
          c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H6c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V8h26V28z M30,6H4V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h22
          c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V6z M17,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,16.7,15.3,18,17,18z M16,14h2v2h-2V14z M9,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,24.7,7.3,26,9,26z M8,22h2v2H8V22z M9,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3
          c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,16.7,7.3,18,9,18z M8,14h2v2H8V14z"/>
        </svg>
                
            
        <svg class="side-svg" id="Line_5" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
          <path class="st0" d="M18,16.4c1.3-1.7,2-3.9,2-6.4c0-5.5-4-10-9-10C6,0,2,4.5,2,10c0,2.4,0.8,4.6,2,6.4c-2.3,0.8-4,3-4,5.6v4
          c0,3.3,2.7,6,6,6h10c3.3,0,6-2.7,6-6v-4C22,19.4,20.3,17.2,18,16.4z M4,10c0-4.4,3.1-8,7-8c3.9,0,7,3.6,7,8s-3.1,8-7,8
          C7.1,18,4,14.4,4,10z M20,25.5c0,2.5-2.2,4.5-4.9,4.5H6.9C4.2,30,2,28,2,25.5v-3c0-2.1,1.6-3.9,3.8-4.4C7.2,19.3,9,20,11,20
          c2,0,3.8-0.7,5.2-1.9c2.2,0.5,3.8,2.2,3.8,4.4V25.5z M23,8h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1h-8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1
          C22,7.6,22.4,8,23,8z M31,24h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,24.4,31.6,24,31,24z M31,12h-8
          c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h8c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,12.4,31.6,12,31,12z M31,18h-6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h6
          c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C32,18.4,31.6,18,31,18z"/>
        </svg>
                  
                  
        <svg class="side-svg" id="Line_12" viewBox="0 0 26 32" >
          <path class="st0" d="M14,0h-2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v28c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C16,0.9,15.1,0,14,0z M14,29
          c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V3c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M4,9H2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2
          c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V11C6,9.9,5.1,9,4,9z M4,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V12c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M24,16h-2
          c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v12c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V18C26,16.9,25.1,16,24,16z M24,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V19
          c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z"/>
        </svg>
                
                  
        <svg class="side-svg" id="Line_6" 
          viewBox="0 0 32 32">
          <path class="st0" d="M26,24H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1
          c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,24.4,26.6,24,26,24z M11,27.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4
          c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,26.3,12.3,27.4,11,27.4z M26,8H14.9c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3C9.1,5,7.6,6.3,7.1,8H6
          C5.4,8,5,8.4,5,9c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h1.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,8.4,26.6,8,26,8z M11,11.4
          c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4C13.4,10.3,12.3,11.4,11,11.4z M26,16h-2.1
          c-0.4-1.7-2-3-3.9-3c-1.9,0-3.4,1.3-3.9,3H6c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1h10.1c0.4,1.7,2,3,3.9,3c1.9,0,3.4-1.3,3.9-3H26
          c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1C27,16.4,26.6,16,26,16z M20,19.4c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.4c0-1.3,1.1-2.4,2.4-2.4c1.3,0,2.4,1.1,2.4,2.4
          C22.4,18.3,21.3,19.4,20,19.4z M28,0H4C1.8,0,0,1.8,0,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h24c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28
          c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H4c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h24c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V28z"/>
        </svg>
```

However if this is not what you need and you need to keep the same size for your icons you may use a different `viewBox` for the first and the third icon:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:50px}
```

```html
<svg class="side-svg" id="Line_2" viewBox="1 0 32 32" > 
          <path class="st0" id="a" d="M25,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,16.7,23.3,18,25,18z M24,14h2v2h-2V14z M25,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C22,24.7,23.3,26,25,26z M24,22h2v2h-2V22z M17,26c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3
          c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,24.7,15.3,26,17,26z M16,22h2v2h-2V22z M28,0H6C3.8,0,2,1.8,2,4v24c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4h22
          c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4V4C32,1.8,30.2,0,28,0z M30,28c0,1.1-0.9,2-2,2H6c-1.1,0-2-0.9-2-2V8h26V28z M30,6H4V4c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2h22
          c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V6z M17,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C14,16.7,15.3,18,17,18z M16,14h2v2h-2V14z M9,26
          c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,24.7,7.3,26,9,26z M8,22h2v2H8V22z M9,18c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3
          c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3C6,16.7,7.3,18,9,18z M8,14h2v2H8V14z"/>
        </svg>
                  
                  
        <svg class="side-svg" version="1.1" id="Line_12" 
          viewBox="-3 0 32 32" >
          <path class="st0" id="kk" d="M14,0h-2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v28c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V2C16,0.9,15.1,0,14,0z M14,29
          c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V3c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M4,9H2c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2
          c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V11C6,9.9,5.1,9,4,9z M4,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V12c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z M24,16h-2
          c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v12c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h2c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V18C26,16.9,25.1,16,24,16z M24,29c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V19
          c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1V29z"/>
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of paths in your SVGs are 32px by 32px, so set set your viewBox="0 0 32 32" and then scale the SVGs by applying width to the `svg` element, **not** to the `path` or `rect` elements inside of it:

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

In order to create a rectangle you shall set the left and top position of the rectangle and set its width and height:

```
<svg class="rect-svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="32" width="32"></rect>
</svg>
```

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/greghvns/9aj0qymL/3/

Answer (score -2):

Add class to your svg element, then in your css use "font-size" property and add value you need :

svg.YourClassName {font-size: 40px;}

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with CSS font-size property, it says in the question title: *Why am I unable to apply height and width to my SVG path elements?*